# How to use Backbone collection's create method correctly

Tags: django, backbone.js

I found that when I use the collection.create to create a new model, backbone will send a post request, but the post data is incorrect
for example
collection.create({name:'test'})
backbone will send POST data using "{name:'test'}" as key, and "" as value,
but I want the POST data by using name as key, 'test' as value,
can anybody no how to setting it,

I use django as the server

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Unless you change it backbone's collections use Backbone.sync to communicate with your backend.

In the docs they say:

> With the default implementation, when Backbone.sync sends up a
>   request to save a model, its attributes will be passed, serialized as
>   JSON, and sent in the HTTP body with content-type application/json

So I guess you need to do something like this in your django view

```
json.load(request.POST)
```

or use a custom sync function that does not serialize the data to json

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to parse the raw post data string and parse it into a python dict.

```
import json
data = json.loads(request.raw_post_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also set

```
Backbone.emulateJSON = true;
```

as per http://backbonejs.org/#Sync-emulateJSON